# How to make client C and B receive DHCP from client A?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vmware-workstation, slackware

Using VMWare Workstation 7.1, Client A is my Linux server with Slackware 13.1, I have set it up as bridge so i can access it from my external network, Client B will be a Windows XP and C will be a Vista Home.

- What setup do i need to do on the VMWare so Client B and C would look like into a switch where Client A is the one that tell them which network they will have ?

Normally if it was 3 computers on a switch this would be a simple:

Client A (server) on the wan port and the clients B and C on port 1 and 2 and my server would have a DHCP server on to provide it.

But on the VM it seems different so I am not sure on how do I link them. Initially i did not make the VM's inside a Team do I need to copy/move them as a Team as well ?

---

**Appreciate any information that can help out on how it has to be setup, if i have to create a different network or w/e within the VMWare Workstation.**

---

What i want is client B to be into a VLAN and C into another VLAN where both VLANs are handled by client A.

so VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 would not see each other but would both be handled by Client A dhcp server.

Client A has eth0 as internet, so eth1 would be the dhcp server.

And what i don't know is how do i setup that on the VMWare, if i have to create a new network device on Client A that will take with both VLANs or what...

If doing the 2 VLANs is not possible knowing how to acomplish 1 VLAN would be ok aswell.

Comment: Are all three hosts configured as using bridged networking? If so they should all be within the same broadcast domain and should be able to receive DHCP leases from Host A, so long as there's not another DHCP server in the broadcast domain that could be conflicting.

Comment: @brent Host A receives the dhcp from my switch hence the others would receive from it aswell which wouldnt workout, thus i have the company server on that board and it could generte conflicts so i would like to maintain the 2nd 2 clients withint the VM using Host A as their server for anything.

Comment: in resume i wanted to use the VMWare netwok setup to produce this internal setup not sure what it is called, im trying the available options on the network options of the vmware but didnt worked out yet

Comment: Could you clarify, you want `A` to be giving DHCP leases to `B` & `C` for the same network that `A` received a lease for from your switch or for a different network?

Comment: @brent updated bellow the bolded text on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client A:

- eth0(VMnet0) Bridge setup (internet)
- eth1(VMnet4) custom network with no hosts,
  bridges, local dhcps from vmware

Client B and C:

- eth0(VMnet4) custom network with no hosts,
  bridges, local dhcps from vmware

With the above setup i could merge the VMs networks with Client A allowing it to distribute the ips and internet to them.

With the option `Use local DHCP service to distribute IP address to VMs` unchecked, you can use your own DHCP server from Client A into that network.

See bellow for a sample image of what the custom network looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to provide DHCP from A Client, you should not use Bridged Networking but Host Only. Indeed except if you want your Client A to offer DHCP Leases on your whole Lan, you shoud edit every VM and choose Host-Only Networking. By this way you will be able to make your vms interact the way you want. Before that you will need to disable the DHCP on the Host-Only Interface. For that click on Edit then virtual Network Editor. You will see the interfaces already set up choose Host Only and uncheck Use Local DHCP ...... at the bottom of the window.